# Remote access users with passwords with active directory

Tags: windows, remote, active-directory

We are changing our active directory policy for our users to finally have passwords. Which is good because they don't have any passwords yet. But with passwords there arises a problem with remote accessibility.

I'm currently managing all users per remote desktop sessions. I usually remote in at night and with everyone getting their own passwords, I'll have an access problem.

Is there any good way to access a remote user account as administrator without knowing the user's password and with no explicit invitation by the user?

Comment: Why do you need to access the computer as the user?  Your administrative account should be able to connect and do any required maintenance.

Comment: Hi - as mentioned above in a scenario such as this, you can enable a local admin account on all the computers with the same password thus negating the need to know each users domain password.

Comment: The problem would be users yammering about programm xy not working. Mostly it is a user specific setting what causes the problem. That fore logging in as the said user makes things easy to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a domain environment, as long as you are a domain admin (or a member of a group that has local admin rights on all your computers), then you will not have any issues connecting to a computer remotely.

You will not, however, be able to log on remotely *as that user* unless you know their password.  This is probably a serious change from the way you've been doing things.  Unfortunately, this is something that you will have to get used to.  Windows does not allow you to impersonate another user's logon.

Comment: And for good reason. Impersonating a user's login can lead accountability issues down the line.

Comment: You can impersonate an other user by steeling their authentication tokens with metasploit :P 
But you are absolutely correct. Impersonating an other user is not the way to go!
I'm resetting the password in AD to be able to connect to the users accounts. By this way the user will know I have been there. After troubleshooting I reset the password again with the force change password on first login.